# How do I get the time from a time server like time.google.com using ntpq?

Tags: ntp

I just want to get the time from time.euro.apple.com or time.google.com

I don't want to set anything, or sync anything, I just want to know what they think the time is.

I have ntpq

Answer (score 1):

Open the /etc/ntp.conf file and add the NTP server from google

```
server time.google.com
```

The same way you can do this in chronyd config file: /etc/chrony.conf

You can query server from terminal:

```
ntpdate time.google.com
```

Actually, the command

```
ntpq -c "rv 0 clock" time.google.com
```

will return the time of the server in standard format

You have to install

```
sudo apt install ntp
```

To be able to use it.

Comment: I don't want to add the time server, I just want to query it.

Is there not a single line command I can type into the console that will return the time?

Comment: I edited my answer. See it.

Comment: `ntpq -c "rv 0 clock" time.google.com` returns `***Request timed out` twice for me. But it works fine with the NTP server provided by my ISP. There seems to be some difference in how the NTP servers are configured or implemented.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the supposedly deprecated `ntpdate` you can use that,

```
ntpdate -qu time.google.com
```

The `-qu` flags query the timeserver without attempting to set the local clock. You can provide multiple timeservers on the single command line if you want to